# Interdependent excel drop downs

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I am creating a leave and absence sheet, what I need is, to have a drop-down in cell `A1` values *1-5* and a drop down in `A2` values *1-5*, however where I’m hitting a wall. I need them to work in conjunction with each other, and the total not to exceed *5*.

I.e. if `A1` = *3* cell `A2` can only be *0*, *1* or *2*. And vice versa, if `A2` if filled in first `A1` can only be the remainder between value of `A2` and *5*.

Firstly is it possible I’m not sure?

if so how?

How this makes sense

Comment: Perhaps not so elegant, but you could just have a table where you specify the values for one drop down given the choice in the other. And then work with named ranges in the data validation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 helper arrays somewhere, for example `D1` and `E1`:

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SEQUENCE(6-A2,1,0,1)
```

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SEQUENCE(6-A1,1,0,1)
```

In `A1` choose data validation "list" and refer to `D1#` array.

In `A2` choose data validation "list" and refer to `E1#` array
[image]

Result:

[image]